# Is there any way to create a prescript to make a request with a certificate in Postman?

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to create a pre request script to make a request with a certificate without the need to apply local files?

My unsuccessful attempt is as follows:

```
var cert_env = pm.environment.get('cert')
var key_env = pm.environment.get('key')

var cert = Buffer.from(cert_env, 'base64').toString('utf8')
var key = Buffer.from(cert_env, 'base64').toString('utf8')

pm.request.certificate = {
    cert,
    key,
}
```